# Player Head Movement Detection Bukkit

Tags: java, bukkit

today I'm here to ask you a question, on Minecraft in particular in the PaperMc development (Bukkit Fork) I'm trying to create the "animations" effect like the famous Hypixel lootboxes (Opening phase) so I needed know how I could identify the PlayerHeadMovement Event. I tried with

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
  System.out.println("A");
}
```

But it would appear not to detect head movement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event that specifically focuses on the movement of the player's head.

You can, however, on the PlayerMoveEvent get the from and to movements.

So, to see if the player's head has moved, your code could look like:

```java
private boolean hasPlayerHeadMoved(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
  Location from = e.getFrom();
  Location to = e.getTo();
  return from.getYaw() != to.getYaw() || from.getPitch() != to.getPitch();
}
```

In your event handler, you would then call the method:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
  boolean headHasMoved = hasPlayerHeadMoved(e);
}
```